# Remote post data of json not populating $_POST

Tags: apache2, php, post

I have a standard build of Apache running on Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.3.10.

I'm looking to have a REST server running on it but I ran into problems. For now there is one index.php which is doing a `print_r($_POST);`

By using this tool https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/ I am posting data to the page. If I set the data to be sent as x-www-form-urlencoded then the `$_POST` variable is populated.

However, if I set the data to be sent as `application/json` the `$_POST` variable isn't populated, but the raw data is available in HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.

The reason I am testing in in this way is this is the same behaviour I am seeing when I am running the REST server (https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver). So i think this must be an Apache problem.

HAs anyone else had this issue? I dont have much experience with running REST servers so it may well be something I am doing wrong.

Comment: That how it suppose to be.

Comment: I dont understand? How would you access the posted data?

Comment: `but the raw data is available in HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` ... also see http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#refsect2-wrappers.php-unknown-unknown-descriptiop http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data

Comment: I haven't implemented a REST server before so I'm struggling a little. If the $_POST variable isn't populated then the REST server I'm trying to implement will not work, yet it works for everyone else?

Comment: If you question was `how to get the posted data?` then it would be easy answered however it is not.

Comment: And how do you access the posted data?

Answer (score 0):

That is how it suppose to be. however if you want the posted data you can

```
$postdata = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```